# Lighttpd limit download connections global/overall

Tags: lighttpd, http-live-streaming

could you help me to limit the downloads on lighttpd?
I'm use Lighty to provide HLS stream to my Customers (downloading .TS/M3U8 Files to get live stream). My server have 1 Gbit upload BW and when there are too many users they are watching the stream, the stream lagging and freezing. How can i tell Lighty to acceppt only like 800 Users they can access the .TS or .M3U8 files at same time?

Comment: Docs: [Traffic Shaping](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_TrafficShaping), [server.max-connections](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Server_max-connectionsDetails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the number of connections to lighttpd with `server.max-connections = 800` Or by limiting file descriptors i.e. `server.max-fds = 1600` However this wont give you the nice fall back you are looking for.

I would suggest handling this problem by handling the stream in a scripting language such as php or nodejs.

Comment: Dear Oliver, Thanks for your answer! This is what i was looking for. But, have a question to your suggestion, to use e.g. PHP: I'm trying to minimize the Server load. At the moment i'm receiving 40 HLS Streams with FFMpeg and like Proxying it.. So I do not have any Encoding or whatever, and my little (Stream "Source") server (dual core/4gb ram) has like 30% Load.. Thats OK, but, what will happen, when i provide the every 40 Streams trought PHP? I Think the load will be more then 100% ... or?

Comment: Hi Chris, I love lighttpd for as web server but its designed to be very light weight it tends to fall down when you try doing anything complicated with it. Regarding php, I think its something you will have to test in practice to see how it would affect your particular server. That said with a simple redirect rather than buffering the stream through php i wouldn't imagine the load to be particularly high.